# Group by years elapsed

Tags: mysql, grouping, date-range

I am trying to run a query that groups contacts by a date field and then returns the count for each grouping. If the date field has a null value that is one group, if the date field is 10+ years ago that is another group, if the date field is 3-10 years ago that's a third grouping, and if the date field is <3 years ago that is the final grouping.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add in which language you are writing this query? (And also add it as tag) Example: mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CASE statement in the GROUP clause:

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN floor(DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)/365) < 3 THEN '<3'
            WHEN floor(DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)/365) < 10 THEN '3-10'
            WHEN floor(DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)/365) = 10 THEN '=10'
            ELSE '>10' 
        END AS `Length`
FROM    ...
WHERE   ...
GROUP   BY  CASE 
                WHEN floor(DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)/365) < 3 THEN '<3'
                WHEN floor(DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)/365) < 10 THEN '3-10'
                WHEN floor(DATEDIFF(EndDate, StartDate)/365) = 10 THEN '=10'
                ELSE '>10' 
            END
ORDER   BY Length ASC;
```

If your end date is now, just use `NOW()`.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86b630/2

```
SELECT IF(my_date IS NULL, 'NO DATE', 
          IF(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(my_date)>10,'>10', 
            IF(YEAR(NOW())-YEAR(my_date)>3,'3-10','<3')
          )
         ) `period`, COUNT(id)
FROM contacts
GROUP BY `period`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect where you prepare the values and then parse them and group them:

```
select case 
when elapsed is null then 'missing'
when elapsed <= 1095 then 'new'
when elapsed <= 3650 then 'middle'
else 'old'
end as period, count(*)
from
(select datediff(now(), yourdate) period from yourtable) t
group by period
```